# breeze: related entity load error

Tags: breeze

Next query fails with error "Object doesn't support method 'getProperty'":

```
breeze.EntityQuery
   .from("Accounts")
   .expand('settlementOrganization,managementCompany')
   .using(manager).execute()
```

Error occurs when breeze is setting related entity managementCompany for account:

exception info from Chrome:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at defaultPropertyInterceptor [as _$interceptor] (breeze.debug.js:5083:49)
    at ko.computed.write (breeze.debug.js:15978:34)
    at dependentObservable [as managementCompany] (knockout-3.0.0.js:1496:31)
    at proto.setProperty (breeze.debug.js:16017:31)
    at updateRelatedEntity (breeze.debug.js:14456:26)
    at mergeRelatedEntity (breeze.debug.js:14393:13)
    at breeze.debug.js:14376:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at updateEntity (breeze.debug.js:14374:41)
    at mergeEntity (breeze.debug.js:14345:13)
```

Code in `defaultPropertyInterceptor` expects entity and tries to use it's method `getProperty`, but istead of entity we have there raw entity data (breeze.debug.js:4961).

Metadata for Account and Company types is ok. I can load companies separately and they will be set to existing accounts peacefully. But loading accounts with extend throws error.

Is it bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of problem.

I'm using breeze with web api and EFContextProvider. For security purposes I added attribute Queryable above my method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Queryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 3)]
public IQueryable<Account> Accounts()
{
   return _contextProvider.Context.Accounts;
}
```

I thought that breeze won't conflict with this attribute, but when I removed attribute, everything started to work fine. Also same attribute broke inlineCount for other IQueriable source.

Comment: The is a [BreezeQueryable] attribute that you can use in place of [Queryable] for this purpose.  The reason for [BreezeQueryable] is that the .NET [Queryable] attribute specifies WebApi serialization and  formatting that breaks Breeze.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use [BreezeQueryable] then.

Comment: @JayTraband Why does [BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 1)] allow to use queries with expand? I have query with expand and select, that successfully expands reference property even though attribute should permit it.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question?

Comment: It seems, I can not permit query expansion by setting BreezeQueryableAttribute.MaxExpansionDepth to 0 or 1. Question was about that.

Comment: The BreezeQueryableAttribute MaxExpansionDepth allows you to set the number of levels of expansion you want to permit.  The default is 2, ( same as with the QueryableAttribute.  I would set it to 3 or greater if you want to have heavily nested expansions.  Take a look at the DocCode sample for examples of its use.

Comment: I really tried to find docs on BreezeQueryableAttribute or QueryableAttribute, but to no avail. Thanks for answer!